Reactjs + Capacitor Barcode Scanner: Execution failed for task ':capacitor-barcode-scanner:compileDebugKotlin'
Edited
I still don't know the solution to this but I change from using @capacitor/barcode-scanner to html5-qrcode npm package. It still gives off the same functionalities but I don't have to deal with the error anymore.
But if you know the solution to my issue, feel free to share.

I'm using @capacitor/barcode-scanner in a reactjs project. The web version runs perfectly, but an error occurs for the mobile app ver.
I got this error when running the application

Execution failed for task ':capacitor-barcode-scanner:compileDebugKotlin'.
Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (17) and 'compileDebugKotlin' (21).

I tried to change the java version in capacitor.build.gradle file but it will revert back to original when sync.
I also install jdk 17 and jdk 21 to try which one is suitable, but still received the same error.
Here are the solutions I've tried:
Link 1
Link 2
Link 3
Does the error come from Capacitor Barcode Scanner plugin or the Android?

If you are using latest JDK to your project then you can make changes in build.gradle(app-level) and your project will run successfully.
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_21 // Adjust the version to the one that works for your project.
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_21 // Adjust the version to the one that works for your project.
}

and
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '21'  // Adjust the version to the one that works for your project.
}


I'm using capacitor, and it doesn't allows me to change the java version in compileOptions. After I change and sync, it will revert back to the original version.

If jdk 21 version not works.
Then java 17 is always safer option to choose.
in gradle change source and target compatibility to 17 version for better stability

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

As I said above, both jdk doesn't solve the error.
